# C iterate through char array with a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, sizeof

I am very new in C and was wondering about how to get each element of an array using a pointer. Which is easy if and only if you know the size of the array.
So let the code be:

`#include <stdio.h>`

```
int main (int argc, string argv[]) {
    char * text = "John Does Nothing";
    char text2[] = "John Does Nothing";

    int s_text = sizeof(text); // returns size of pointer. 8 in 64-bit machine
    int s_text2 = sizeof(text2); //returns 18. the seeked size.

    printf("first string: %s, size: %d\n second string: %s, size: %d\n", text, s_text, text2, s_text2);

    return 0;
}
```

Now I want to determine the size of `text`. to do this, I found out, that the String will end with a `'\0'` character. So I wrote the following function:

```c
int getSize (char * s) {
    char * t; // first copy the pointer to not change the original
    int size = 0;

    for (t = s; s != '\0'; t++) {
        size++;
    }

    return size;
}
```

This function however does not work as the loop seems to not terminate.

So, is there a way to get the actual size of the `char`s the pointer points on?

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't change anything in the result. doesn't matter whether I use `s != '\0'` or `*s != '\0'` or `t != '\0'` or `*t != '\0'`, it ends up still not terminating…

Comment: You're reimplementing `strlen`.

Comment: Your function doesn't use `s`, so what's the point in preserving "the original" value?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead of checking the pointer you have to check the current value. You can do it like this:

```
int getSize (char * s) {
    char * t; // first copy the pointer to not change the original
    int size = 0;

    for (t = s; *t != '\0'; t++) {
        size++;
    }

    return size;
}
```

Or more concisely:

```
int getSize (char * s) {
    char * t;    
    for (t = s; *t != '\0'; t++)
        ;
    return t - s;
}
```

Comment: Only problem with this one is, it returns always one char less. So adding +1 in the end works. Only if the string isn't empty to begin with. But thanks! Ima work around it now :D

Comment: Also, if you are using an empty loop, make it easier to detect by using empty-braces, e.g.  `for (t = s; *t; t++) {}`  (you at least moved the `';'` to a line of its own -- that was good)

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo in this for loop

```
for (t = s; s != '\0'; t++) {
            ^^^^^^^^^
```

I think you mean

```
for (t = s; *t != '\0'; t++) {
            ^^^^^^^^^
```

Nevertheless in general the function does not provide a value that is equivalent to the value returned by the operator `sizeof` even if you will count also the terminating zero. Instead it provides a value equivalent to the value returned by the standard function `strlen`.

For example compare the output of this code snippet

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//...

char s[100] = "Hello christopher westburry";

printf( "sizeof( s ) = %zu\n", sizeof( s ) );
printf( "strlen( s ) = %zu\n", strlen( s ) + 1 );
```

So your function just calculates the length of a string.

It would be more correctly to define it the following way (using pointers)

```
size_t getSize ( const char * s ) 
{
    size_t size = 0;

    while ( *s++ ) ++size;

    return size;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. 

size_t getSize ( const char * s ) 
{
    size_t size = 0;

    while ( *s++ ) ++size;

    return size;
}
it works even with pointer to any other container with contiguous memory as long as *s is a pointer to the first element and the elements are stored in contiguous memory such that the end of the container produces false.